# XPathExpression AddSort

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Is it possible to sort the elements and not only the nodes using XPathExpression.AddSort?

If I change the example code on the MSDN documentation for [XPathExpression.AddSort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2hhe5h7.aspx) a little so I request an element and not the whole node the sort order does not work.

```
var doc = new XPathDocument("contosoBooks.xml");
var nav = doc.CreateNavigator();

var expr = nav.Compile("/bookstore/book/title");

expr.AddSort("title", XmlSortOrder.Descending,
               XmlCaseOrder.None, "", XmlDataType.Number);

var iterator = nav.Select(expr);
while (iterator.MoveNext())
{
    Console.WriteLine(iterator.Current);
}
```

I would expect this output:

```
The Gorgias
The Confidence Man
The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin
```

But the output is this:

```
The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin
The Confidence Man
The Gorgias
```

Here is the xml file for your reference

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<bookstore>
  <book genre="autobiography" publicationdate="1981-03-22" ISBN="1-861003-11-0">
    <title>The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin</title>
    <author>
      <first-name>Benjamin</first-name>
      <last-name>Franklin</last-name>
    </author>
    <price>8.99</price>
  </book>
  <book genre="novel" publicationdate="1967-11-17" ISBN="0-201-63361-2">
    <title>The Confidence Man</title>
    <author>
      <first-name>Herman</first-name>
      <last-name>Melville</last-name>
    </author>
    <price>11.99</price>
  </book>
  <book genre="philosophy" publicationdate="1991-02-15" ISBN="1-861001-57-6">
    <title>The Gorgias</title>
    <author>
      <name>Plato</name>
    </author>
    <price>9.99</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

Comment: Besides the answer below (which you should accept by the way), you should also specify the correct `XmlDataType` which should be `XmlDataType.Text` for a string-based sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a duplicate question - see [XPathExpression AddSort fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848192/xpathexpression-addsort-fails)

So in your case code has to be like:

```
var expr = nav.Compile("/bookstore/book");

expr.AddSort("title", XmlSortOrder.Descending,
           XmlCaseOrder.None, "", XmlDataType.Number);
```

or

```
var expr = nav.Compile("/bookstore/book/title");

expr.AddSort(".", XmlSortOrder.Descending,
           XmlCaseOrder.None, "", XmlDataType.Number);
```