# XPathExpression AddSort fails

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am tryng to sort a result from an xpath query but it fails.

Ooutput:

```
ABC
DEF
```

But I am expecting:

```
DEF
ABC
```

The source code looks like this, it uses an XML expression and sorts the result:

```
var doc = new XPathDocument("testmsg2.xml");
var nav = doc.CreateNavigator();

const string query = "//Z/X/Code";

var expr = nav.Compile(query);
expr.AddSort("Code",
             XmlSortOrder.Descending,
             XmlCaseOrder.None,
             "",
             XmlDataType.Text);

switch (expr.ReturnType)
{                
    case XPathResultType.NodeSet:
        var nodes = (XPathNodeIterator)nav.Evaluate(expr);

        while (nodes != null && nodes.MoveNext())
        {
            if (nodes.Current == null)
                continue;

            if (nodes.Current.HasChildren)
            {
                var childIter = nodes.Current.SelectChildren(XPathNodeType.All);

                while (childIter.MoveNext())
                {
                    if (childIter.Current != null)
                        Console.WriteLine(childIter.Current.Value);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(nodes.Current.Value);
            }
        }

        break;
}
```

The XML file is simplified for this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Z>
  <X>
    <Code>ABC</Code>
  </X>
  <X>
    <Code>DEF</Code>
  </X>
</Z>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AddSort` method takes an XPath expression that is contextually bound to the `XPathExpression` you've compiled. In your case, the `XPathExpression` is compiled against the `<Code>` element. Doing `AddSort("Code")` implies that you have the following XML:

```
<Code>
    <Code>
    </Code>
</Code>
```

Instead, you can either compile your expression to `X`:

```
const string query = "//Z/X";
```

Or you can sort on the current node (being `Code`), `.`:

```
expr.AddSort(".", XmlSortOrder.Descending, XmlCaseOrder.None, "", XmlDataType.Text);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well your path `//Z/X/Code` selects `Code` elements, the Sort then needs to use a proper relative expression, in your case

```
expr.AddSort(".",
             XmlSortOrder.Descending,
             XmlCaseOrder.None,
             "",
             XmlDataType.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Either remove "/Code" from your query our use "." instead of "Code" in AddSort() - depending on whether you want to select X-nodes or Code-nodes. Currently, you are querying the Code-nodes and then try to sort them by what applying the XPath "Code" to the result returns. But there is nothing that matches "Code" *relative to* a Code-node.

Comment: What if I want to sort the contect and leave /Code there?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not exactly sure what you want to achieve. How do you want your query result look on the first level?

Answer (score -1):

Some alternative using Linq to Xml

```
using System.Xml.XPath;

var document = XDocument.Parse(@"<Z>
                                  <X>
                                    <Code>ABC</Code>
                                  </X>
                                  <X>
                                    <Code>DEF</Code>
                                  </X>
                                 </Z>");

var codeValues = document.XPathSelectElements("//Z/X/Code")
                          .Select(e => e.Value)
                          .OrderByDescending(e => e);
```

You can simplify it even further if you want. You need to take into account performance though. If your xml files are large this won't perform as well I guess. If you only have small files the simplicity of this outweighs the small performance penalty.

Comment: Whilst this isn't technically an incorrect answer, it doesn't relate to the problem that OP is having. It's an alternative, rather than a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the down vote @DanAtkinson. It's stated in the first paragraph that it is an alternative. A working, more elegant alternative nonetheless.

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted you (http://i.imgur.com/o8Qgl9X.png). Although I'll happily admit that I could have faked that image. To what end though, I do not know.